# Script output overwites the old data instead in output file of write to new line

Tags: bash, hadoop, if-statement, cron

I have come with a script to check Name node status. When I ran manually, the Status of namenode written to a file and when I run again the second attempt output adds a new line in the old file. But I have scheduled in cron to run every 15 minutes. But the cron job overwrites the old data and I can see only last run status. How can I add a new line through cron as well?

```
#!/bin/bash   

NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
fname=active.$NOW.log
[ ! -f  $fname ] && > /opt/hd/sh/bin/$fname

if [[ $(hdfs haadmin -ns ATcluster -getServiceState nn1) = *active* ]];
then
  echo "`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` active NN1" >> /opt/hd/sh/bin/$fname
elif [[ $(hdfs haadmin -ns ATcluster -getServiceState nn2) = *active* ]];
then
  echo "`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` active NN2" >> /opt/hd/sh/bin/$fname
else
  echo "`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` stopped state" >> /opt/hd/sh/bin/failed.$NOW.log
fi
```

**Output:**

```
cat active.01-1
cat: active.01-1: No such file or directory
[root@hadmat01 bin]# cat active.01-11-2018.log
2018-01-11 06:00:04 active NN1 --> it should write nw output like below through cron job
[root@hadmat01 bin]# cat failed.01-11-2018.log
20180111 00:00:05 stopped state
20180111 00:15:05 stopped state
20180111 00:30:05 stopped state
20180111 00:45:05 stopped state
```

Answer (score 1):

you problem is in this code:
`fname=active.$NOW.log
[ ! -f  $fname ] && > /opt/hd/sh/bin/$fname`

if this job started from crontab - checking file existanse started from `/`.
And i think location /active.01-11-2018.log doesn't exist. 
So you put emty string in file `/opt/hd/sh/bin/$fname`

you must define absolute path for log destination, or insert string `cd /opt/hd/sh/bin/` before `if` section